# How to get the name of devices lp0 and lp1

Tags: shell, debian

Hello in /dev/usb/lp*

I have 2 printers lp0 and lp1

How can I get their names so I know which one is which

```
udevadm info -a /dev/usb/lp*
```

does not show the device name

Comment: Removing the Python tag.  Also, this is probably better if you ask on Super User.